# Using Cloudinary with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, guzzle, cloudinary

I'm trying to set this up on my project using this package https://github.com/cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel but I haven't been successful.

I followed the setup on the GitHub but I'm not sure I did it right. I see these are needed in the .env

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
CLOUDINARY_NOTIFICATION_URL=
```

And it says those are on the Account Dashboard but I can't see them I only have

```
Cloud name:
API Key:
API Secret: 
API Environment variable: CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://***
Base delivery URL:
Secure delivery URL:
API Base URL:
```

The names don't match, except for the API Environment variable is the CLOUDINARY_URL, but other that one I don't know what goes where.

What do I put for the other two?

I'm also getting either a Guzzle connection error or this

> Cloudinary\Api\Exception\GeneralError
> Server returned unexpected status code - 504 -

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the package author or the API provider.

Answer (score 0):

First I should clarify that cloudinary-laravel is sill in Labs and should not be used for production purposes.

To answer your question, CLOUDINARY_NOTIFICATION_URL as you mentioned in the comment, is a webhook notification mechanism to informing your backend about certain actions. Please refer to https://cloudinary.com/documentation/notifications for more information. So this would be your application endpoint. I'm guessing you are getting 504 is due to the endpoint getting a connection time out.

CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET is an upload preset that you need to set it up on your account first. To learn how to set it up, please also check the following documentation: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_presets.

Hope this helps. If you still stuck, I recommend to open a support ticket with all the details you have in [Cloudinary's Support portal](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)

Regards,
Erwin Lukas

Comment: I removed it and went with the php server side setup instead. Since you know about the topic you think you could help me update an image?

This is how I uploaded it
```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload(
    $request->file('image'),
    $options = array("folder" => "categories/", 'public_id' => $request->name)
);
```

Looking at the docs it says this is the way
```
$api->update($public_id, $options = array());
```

But they don't explain what `$api` is a variable of, or how to set it.

Comment: `$api->update()` is part of Cloudinary's Admin API's [update](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#update_details_of_an_existing_resource) method.

`$api` is the Cloudinary's Admin API's object that needs to be defined first as follow:
`$api = new \Cloudinary\Api();`
Please check the example [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_asset_administration#example).
From your code, I'm not sure what you are trying to update. For most situation, you may want to check [explicit](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#explicit_method) method.

Comment: I'm trying to update the image but keep the same url

Comment: Update as in a new image but with the same public id? If yes, then you should [Uploda](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) end point and pass the same public id as the parameter.
You may also want to set `"invalidate"=>true` to make sure the CDN is invalidated

Answer (score 0):

At least to upload a file to Cloudinary, the only thing you need is the API Environment variable. So in your .env file, you would paste the API Environment variable in this manner:

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://YOUR_API_KEY:****************************
```

Note that after you copied the API Environment variable, you will need to remove the leading 'CLOUDINARY_URL'.

**Hence this is wrong: CLOUDINARY_URL=CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://...**

You don't need to set the CLOUDINARY_NOTIFICATION_URL to get it off with basic uploading.