# Issue in configuring Cloudinary in laravel 8

Tags: configuration, cloud, laravel-8, cloudinary

I am having an issue with configuring Cloudinary version 2.9 in laravel 8.
getting the error given in the picture. And I also want to know which files I must change.

I put API key, secret key, and cloud name in vendor/cloudinary/src/configuration/cloudconfig

[image]

```
and  
following in vendor/cloudinary/src/configuration/configuration
const CLOUDINARY_URL_ENV_VAR = 'CLOUDINARY_URL=*****************************************';
```

Also not getting any variable in the .env file, also not getting file named Cloudinary in /config  folder

Comment: you should be able to just set an env. variable called `CLOUDINARY_URL` and the SDK should pick it up... see https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration#setting_the_cloudinary_url_environment_variable . Can you try that?

Comment: there is nothing in the .env file keys like api , secret .

Comment: I have tried this but still giving same error.

Comment: are you using https://github.com/cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel ?

Comment: Yes,@Tom I am using from github.

Comment: so you need to put the credentials in your `.env` file, this is created in the root directory of your application and will contain a `.env.example` or `.env` file and add (in new lines)

CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=xxx
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=xxxx
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME=xxxx

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: try this approach too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707590/using-cloudinary-with-laravel-8